# Latest bower update (0.5.1) broke Polymer on my website

Tags: polymer

I realized I never updated Polymer since I first installed with Bower, so I ran `bower update` on my website's project root and it appeared to update fine, with the exception that it was finding two different versions, 0.3.6 and 0.5.1 I believe. I checked the [Github releases section](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/releases) for Polymer and saw that 0.5.1 is the latest stable release so when the option occured I hit 0.5.1. Now when I go to my website on my AppEngine dev server I see this:

`Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

On a bunch of Polymer elements, like

`core-collapse.html:59`

`core-selection.html:77`

`core-selector.html:78`

I'm not sure where I went wrong! Is 0.5.1 not the stabls release? I am very new to terminal stuff so am not sure where to go to try to fix this. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

**edit: I didn't realize I needed to use /webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js instead of platform.js now. I'll leave this up in case anyone else is confused in the future!**